# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, function, tuples, typeerror

I am currently five weeks into learning Python, and I am trying to program a very simplified version of Blackjack. I am close to done, but I cannot get past this certain error message:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Here is the code:

```
import random

print("Welcome to my Black Jack program! Let's play!\n")

def deal_card():
    Jack = 10
    Queen = 10
    King = 10
    Ace = 1
    cards = [Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King]
    drawn_card = cards[random.randrange(1, 13)]
    return drawn_card

def get_player_score():
    first_player_card = deal_card()
    second_player_card = deal_card()
    sum_player_cards = first_player_card + second_player_card
    print ("Your card total is: ", sum_player_cards, ".", sep="")
    while sum_player_cards < 21:
        choice = int(input("Would you like to hit or stay? Enter 1 for 'hit' or 2 for 'stay'. "))
        if choice == 1:
            new_card = deal_card()
            sum_player_cards = sum_player_cards + new_card
            print ("Your new total is: ", sum_player_cards, ".", sep="")
        elif choice == 2:
            return()
        else:
            print("Please choose 'hit' or stay'.")
            choice = input("Would you like to hit or stay? Enter 1 for 'hit' or 2 for 'stay'. ")
    if sum_player_cards > 21:
        return()
    return int(sum_player_cards)

def get_dealer_score():
    first_dealer_card = deal_card()
    second_dealer_card = deal_card()
    sum_dealer_cards = int(first_dealer_card + second_dealer_card)
    while sum_dealer_cards <= 16:
        another_dealer_card = deal_card()
        sum_dealer_cards = sum_dealer_cards + another_dealer_card
    if sum_dealer_cards > 16:
        print("The dealer's card total is: ", sum_dealer_cards, ".", sep="")
    return int(sum_dealer_cards)

def main():
    player_score = get_player_score()
    dealer_score = get_dealer_score()
    if player_score > dealer_score and player_score <= 21:
        print("You win!")
    elif dealer_score > player_score and dealer_score <= 21:
        print("The dealer wins!")
    elif dealer_score <= 21 and player_score > 21:
        print("You've gone bust! Dealer wins!")
    elif dealer_score > 21:
        print("The dealer busts! You win!")

main()
```

I am barely five chapters into *Starting Out with Python*, 4th ed. So I should only be using principles covered through those first five chapters.

Comment: Statements like `return()` return an empty tuple, `()`. If you don't want to return anything, use `return`. In your case, `return 0` might be more appropriate, don't know.

Comment: Curious about the various `int(...)` calls; that rarely seems necessary, other than perhaps for user input (which is always a string).

Comment: This was begging for print statements for debugging. Probably should do that first next time.

Comment: Thanks, @Evert. Changing `return()` to `return` seems to improved things. But now I get an `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'` error message. And you're right, I think most of the `int`s are unnecessary. That was an artifact of me trying to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to @Evert and @Wiggy A., I fixed the `return` statements in my `get_player_score` function. Instead of `return 0` or `return`, I realized I needed to change the statements to `return sum_player_cards`. I thought that `return` statements could only return values when used at the end of a function definition. But they can be used in `if`, `elif`, and `else` statements as well. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Note that if there is no proper value to return, raising an exception may the correct thing to do instead (such as a `ValueError(...)`).